# Why anchor href property different from href attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom

there is a html code like this:

```
<a href="http://domain.xxx?a=b&c=d" >text</a>
```

and when I use the dom api to get the href attribute.

```
document.querySelector('a').href
```

Why is the value of `href` property different from attribute value?

```
http://domain.xxx/?a=b&c=d
```

```js
alert(document.querySelector('a').href)
```

```html
<a href="http://domain.xxx?a=b&c=d" >text</a>
```

Comment: If you want exact text use `document.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href')`

Comment: Check the comment! the above comment is your answer!

Comment: To answer your question, the href property is always the absolute version of the path in the href attribute

Answer (score -2):

use the Jquery instead

Suppose your anchor tag is look like below

```
<a id="anchorTag" href="http://domain.xxx?a=b&c=d" >text</a>
```

Use the Jquery below

```
$("#anchorTag").attr("href");
```

This will return the href value

Let me know if it is helpful